# Should we try to do better with Nokogiri?

Tags: discussion

Excerpt from the [Nokogiri documentation](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri#installation):

> There are currently 1,237 Stack Overflow questions about Nokogiri installation. The vast majority of them are out of date and therefore incorrect. **Please do not use Stack Overflow.**

(Git blame suggests this advisory is at least 3 years old.)

Nokogiri, for those unfamiliar, is a widely-used XML parsing library for Ruby. The "happy path" for its installation is pretty simple (`gem install nokogiri`) but off the happy path there are a lot of dependencies. Should we be trying to update these questions to offer better answers for those trying (and failing?) to install it? Or should we just mark the old ones as old and move on?

Comment: You're free to do either or both of those things.  If you think SO should be providing more/better answers for questions in that topic then *post good answers in that topic*.  If you see bad answers in that topic then downvote them accordingly, so others can see that they're bad.

Comment: But... package installation questions are borderline at best, do we really need 1237 of them (or however many there are now)?

Comment: Hmm.  What would be examples of poor questions about Nokogiri that they'd reference? A blanket statement saying not to use the site doesn't help anyone, really...

Comment: *Or should we just mark the old ones as old and move on?* That could get tricky if you're talking about editing the answer itself and not just leaving a comment. Do any of these posts indicate which version the users are talking about?

Comment: Also, do the problems in those old questions even still exist for new versions? Marking the answer as old would be a moot point if the problem doesn't apply to new versions. (Also, maybe their advisory is outdated; it's not like there isn't new Q&A in the tag)

Comment: I assume back then, the official documentation for Nokogiri installation was not thorough, so users were asking on SO. SO provided workarounds and users were happy. In the meantime, Nokogiri realized this, improved their documentation, *and put an effort to support installation issue more seriously,* **that's actually great**! Now, back to the question, worth considering that searching "nokogiri installation" returned their documentation higher than SO, so I *hope* users will try that first. So, I have the same sentiment as other commenters that it's probably not worth to update old posts.

Comment: In the end, our (SO's) job is not to replace someone's documentation, but to augment it. Users are still free to ask here if they don't get satisfying answer from the official responses. Ideally, it should be 2-way feedback where helpful answers on SO are incorporated on their documentation.

Comment: You can always ask the maintainers.

Comment: You missed out the `Instead, tell us when the above instructions don't work for you. This allows us to both help you directly and improve the documentation.` which gives their motivation for asking that.

Comment: As of writing this, there are 3283 question tagged with [tag:nokogiri], ~25 of them asked this year. It doesn't seem that most of the questions are outdated.

Comment: Do the unhappy path cases have enough overlap in troubleshooting/solutions to create a canonical question/answer pair for installing it that could be kept current with any changes to implementation and used as a broad close as duplicate target?

Answer (score 22):

"How do I install software XYZ" questions are only borderline on-topic even in the best case. Usually, they are highly specific to the version and/or something the user did and/or their environment and thus not useful for the general community. (The old "too localized" close reason.)

Developers referring users to the official documentation and support channels is a *good thing*, IMO. While the warning obviously doesn't reflect well on Stack Overflow, it actually captures very well the reasons *why* such questions make bad Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that Nokogiri installation used to be very problematic and still can be. Just look at the current [official troubleshooting steps](https://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#macos) for Mac installation of Nokogiri, and this is after they have spent literally years trying to improve the installation process. Nokogiri is not pure Ruby. It needs to be locally compiled and linked and it uses patched and otherwise very specific versions of libraries and many users have already installed incompatible versions that traditional package managers would say supersede Nokogiri's. Combine that with dynamic linking and loading of shared libraries and you can get quite a lot of issues. Plus it is an extremely popular package because it by far the best HTML parser available as a Ruby library.

That said, I think this is one of a general class of questions on SO that we should be starting to think seriously about, which is: answers that were correct and useful at the time but which have become outdated and wrong. For example, answers applicable to Ruby before Ruby 2.0, such as "how do you increase the stack size?" or "what is the time complexity of `Array.unshift`?", are now wrong.

I think we should have a formal sunsetting policy where outdated questions are archived, marked prominently as outdated, and linked to updated answers. We can handle this with something like the same kind of flags and voting we currently use for closing questions for other reasons.